# Problems saving to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Good morning everyone, I'm learning to use asp.net core in version 6 and I'm having problems saving a record to the database it shows the following error:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'VehiclePerson'.

From what I know, it is actually because it does not find the table in `"VehiclePerson"` although the connection is made, so I used Scaffolding to obtain the DB from Microsoft SSMS and I created the models and the Context file, so I don't think there are problems with the connection.

This is my VehiclePerson.cs file

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace APITDCON.Models.QQGUAR01;

public partial class VehiclePerson
{
    public string? EmpNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Lastname { get; set; }
    public string? Firstname { get; set; }
    public string? Costcenter { get; set; }
    public string? Department { get; set; }
    public string? CredentNumber { get; set; }
    public string? FromDate { get; set; }
    public string? ToDate { get; set; }
    public string? Rights { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is my VehiclePerson.cs file

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using APITDCON.Models.QQGUAR01;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
namespace APITDCON.Data
{
    public class APITDCONContext : DbContext
    {
        public APITDCONContext(DbContextOptions<APITDCONContext> options) : base(options) 
        {
            

        }
        public DbSet<VehiclePerson> VehiclePerson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my VehiclePerson.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using APITDCON.Models.TANKFARM;
using APITDCON.Models;
using APITDCON.Data;
using System.Collections;



namespace APITDCON.Controllers
{

    public class VehiclePersonController1 : Controller
    {
        private readonly APITDCONContext _apiTDCONContext;
        public VehiclePersonController1(APITDCONContext apiTDCONContext)
        {
            _apiTDCONContext = apiTDCONContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index() 
        {
            List<VehiclePerson> lista = new List<VehiclePerson>();
            lista = GetAllDataDrivers();
            return View(lista);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(VehiclePerson vehiclePersonRequest)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            var vehicleperson = new VehiclePerson()
            {
                EmpNumber = vehiclePersonRequest.EmpNumber,
                Lastname = vehiclePersonRequest.Lastname,
                Firstname = vehiclePersonRequest.Firstname,
                Costcenter = vehiclePersonRequest.Costcenter,
                Department = vehiclePersonRequest.Department,
                CredentNumber = vehiclePersonRequest.CredentNumber,
                FromDate = vehiclePersonRequest.FromDate,
                ToDate = vehiclePersonRequest.ToDate,
                Rights = vehiclePersonRequest.Rights
            };

            using (var db = new Models.QQGUAR01.Qqguar01Context())
            {
                var result = new List<VehiclePerson>();
                result = (from data in db.VehiclePerson
                          select new VehiclePerson
                         {
                             EmpNumber = data.EmpNumber,
                             Lastname = data.Lastname,
                             Firstname = data.Firstname
                         }).ToList();
            }

            _apiTDCONContext.VehiclePerson.Add(vehicleperson);
            _apiTDCONContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Add");
        }
    }
}
```

Database and table

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: "VehiclePerson" (bottom picture) is something that's different from "VEHICLE_PERSON" (2nd picture from the bottom).   P.S. I hate pictures... (to quote [Gargamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargamel))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name defined in your database context is `VehiclePerson`, but your table name in the database is `VEHICLE_PERSON`, the two names do not match.

The easiest way is to change the name of the table `VEHICLE_PERSON` in the database to `VehiclePerson`, or change `public DbSet<VehiclePerson> VehiclePerson { get; set; }` to `public DbSet<VehiclePerson> VEHICLE_PERSON { get; set; }` in your context.

If you want to avoid similar situations in the future, you can use the following commands to migrate and update the database after adding Scaffolding:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

For more details on scaffolding and connecting to the database, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1):

By default EF will use entity name as table name so you can override it in multiple ways, for example using `Table` attribute:

```cs
[Table("VEHICLE_PERSON")]
public partial class VehiclePerson
{
}
```

Comment: Hello Guru Strong, add [Table("VEHICLE_PERSON")] to my program but it still shows an error.

Comment: @LeonardoCarrascoVelazquez check the generated SQL for starters then.

Comment: Sorry for asking so much but how can I print the SQL query.

Comment: @LeonardoCarrascoVelazquez see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#simple-logging)